# Hanshake failure! WebSocket connection and upgrade headers are missing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I have a microservices application running on an ECS Fargate task in private subnet. I created a REST API Gateway which forwards requests to Network Load Balancer, and then NLB redirects the requests to Application Load Balancer. Finally, ALB finds the related container and sends the incoming request to it.

In summary, the flow is Client -> REST API Gateway -> NLB -> ALB -> Fargate Task.

Now, I can call REST endpoints and receive responses successfully. However, one of my applications includes also a websocket endpoint, and I am not able to make a websocket connection (wss) through the REST API Gateway. The problem is that the request I sent to gateway misses connection and upgrade headers. Actually, there was no issue regarding the headers on the local machine, however; the requests I sent to the REST API Gateway does not include those headers when I checked through CloudWatch logs as below.

API Gateway Logs

```
> (6663bb3f-a1c7-45f7-....) Method request headers:
> {Origin=chrome-extension://mdmlhchldhfnfnkfmljgeinlffmdgkjo,
> Sec-WebSocket-Key=oybxAVOYCkNP2bsskgXaJQ==, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0
> (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36, X-Forwarded-Proto=https,
> Sec-WebSocket-Version=13, Host=-------,
> Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, Pragma=no-cache,
> X-Forwarded-Port=443, Sec-WebSocket-Protocol=ocpp1.6,
> X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-610a4fba-73e4f3796a63c23c5f9e3dfb,
> Sec-WebSocket-Extensions=permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits,
> Cache-Control=no-cache, X-Forwarded-For=185.67.125.128,
> Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8}
```

Hence, I observed the following code in the application logs.

```
o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler : Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
```

- Is there any idea to resolve this issue?
- I do not think that I have to create a WebSocket API Gateway, right?

Comment: Having the same problem.

Comment: Any ideas? Stuck in this issue..